# how to connect mongoose correctly to local database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following file app.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const User = require('./User')

mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/restApi')
const con = mongoose.connection

const user = new User({ name: 'Leo' })
user.save().then(() => console.log('User saved'))
```

and this here is User.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

If I run the file now, it seems to work at first, but after a few seconds this error is thrown:

```
C:\Users\<...>\node_rest_api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:151
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\<...>\node_rest_api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:151:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)

Node.js v18.7.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

can anyone help me selving this problem?

Comment: The default port is 27017 so you probably need `mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/restApi')` https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connections

Comment: i tried it out now, but it doesn't work.... i get the same error as before. and 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost also does not work.

Comment: Did you start the mongodb server?

Comment: Well, my Task Manager says that "MongoDB Database Server" is running in the backgroung.